# Clipping features depending upon percent coverage by other features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, polygon, clip

I have a shapefile composed of several thousand square polygons of equal size, arranged in a grid. I have another shapefile with a few dozen circles. The squares are about 1/10th the size of the circles.

I would like to clip the squares using the circles so that if the square is less than halfway inside any one of the circles then it gets left out. If a square is 10% inside one circle and 70% inside another circle it should only be included in the one where it is 70% inside. Some squares will wind up in multiple circles.

[image: screenshot]

I'd like to clip the shapefile with the squares by the one with the circles, but if a square is less than halfway inside a circle then it should be left out completely - just blank space.

Comment: I would highly recommend adding some screenshots to help elucidate your post.

Comment: I've never used Python, nor any other programming language.

Comment: Say you have 10 circles, would you then like to have 10 clipped (fishnet) polygon shapefiles as the output?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to have all 10 in one shapefile, but if they end up in 10 different shapefiles I could just merge them back together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the [Select Layer By Location (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000072000000) tool. Make sure to select the "HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN" option in the Relationships parameter.  To make the selection permanent, use [Copy Features (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000035000000).

---

[image]

[image]